# Error while loading shared libraries when running ghc or ghci

Tags: haskell, shared-libraries, ghc, ghci

> /home/surya/.ghcup/ghc/8.10.4/lib/ghc-8.10.4/bin/ghc: error while loading shared libraries: libtinfo.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

while running **ghc or ghci** in terminal

Ghc version:8.10.4

Ghcup version:The GHCup Haskell installer, version v0.1.14.1

Operating system:Elementary os 5.1.7

I already tried installing ncurses from source. That didn't work.

Comment: not sure here but it's worth a try: usually you don't only need the library but also the dev files - look for `ncurses-devel`, `ncurses-dev`, `libncurses(-dev)`,... and try installing this too: `sudo yum install ncurses-devel`

Comment: oops - Elementary is Ubuntu based right? I think it's `sudo apt-get install ncurses-dev` then

Comment: newer versions might be `sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev` too.

Comment: I installed 
`ncurses-term ncurses-hexedit ncurses-examples ncurses-doc ncurses-bin ncurses-base libtinfo5-dbg libtinfo5 libtinfo5 libtinfo-dev libncursesw5-dev libncursesw5-dbg libncursesw5 libncursesada5-dev libncursesada5 libncursesada-doc libncurses5-dbg libghc-terminal-size-prof libghc-terminal-size-doc libghc-terminal-size-dev libghc-ncurses-prof libghc-ncurses-dev libcunit1-ncurses-dev libcunit1-ncurses lib64tinfo5 lib64ncurses5-dev lib64ncurses5`

Comment: but still ghci and ghc not working